# How to run cluster analysis on R for text based data

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining

Excel Data would contain 36 Factors (basically yes or no Questions) collected from users. Based on this question is there any way to run cluster analysis? I tried using iris example as reference, but as my data is completely text base, trying to figure out a way.

The date would be like:

```
            Q 1     Q 2     Q 3     Q 4     Q 5
People 1    Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes 
People 2    No      Yes     No      Yes     No
People 3    No      No      No      No      No
People 4    Yes     No      Yes     No      Yes 
People 5    No      Yes     No      Yes     No
People 6    Yes     No      Yes     No      Yes 
People 7    No      Yes     No      Yes     No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I reffer to online blogs, Crossvalidated Stackexchange or other resources for the factor analysis, I am showing here an approach, how to get your data numeric.

Here is how I reproduced your data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table("Person ID     Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4     Q5
People 1    Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes 
People 2    No      Yes     No      Yes     No
People 3    No      No      No      No      No
People 4    Yes     No      Yes     No      Yes 
People 5    No      Yes     No      Yes     No
People 6    Yes     No      Yes     No      Yes 
People 7    No      Yes     No      Yes     No") %>% 
  unite("PersonID", Person, ID, sep = "")
```

Now your need to swap the text to factors and than to numeric data.

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(grepl("Q", names(.)), as.factor) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric)
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 6
  PersonID    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 People1      2     2     2     2     2
2 People2      1     2     1     2     1
3 People3      1     1     1     1     1
4 People4      2     1     2     1     2
5 People5      1     2     1     2     1
6 People6      2     1     2     1     2
7 People7      1     2     1     2     1
```

Now you can perform a correlation, which you might need for your factor analysis:

```
df %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  cor()
```

Hope that approach helps.